# All bookmarks and history lost after using separate profile once

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Yesterday, I ran firefox with `firefox -P test_profile` to do something on a test profile. What I wanted to do is some automated testing.

Today, I launched firefox with the `default` profile and my own profile is mostly gone:

- All history is lost
- All bookmarks are lost. This is very serious problem for my work!
- All addons dissapeared, but when I reinstalled them, their data was not lost (eg. tampermonkey scripts are still there after installing tampermonkey).

Layout customization and color scheme is also preserved. But the lost history is way more important. Is there a way to recover it?

Answer (score 0):

Look in you profile directory which is perhaps `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\SOMETHING\Mozilla`.

I suspect Firefox has migrated your data to a new format or something like that, and in doing that, they should have made a backup in this directory.